# Where are the Himalayan Buddhist stupas?

Tags: india, locate-this, ruins, kashmir

I'm trying to locate sacred Himalayan Buddhist stupas and ruins of old fort in Himalayas (Ladakh, Kashmir region) in India.

Where exactly is that place and what's the name of it (name of the place, fort, ruins or whatever is's commonly used)?

[image: Himalayan Buddhist stupas]

<sup>Image credits: [shutterstock](http://www.shutterstock.com/pic-2707453/stock-photo-buddhist-stupas-and-ruins-of-old-fort-in-the-himalayas-ladakh-kashmir-india.html)</sup>

Comment: looks like you've cropped a [shutterstock photo](http://www.shutterstock.com/cat.mhtml?safesearch=1&search_language=en&search_type=similar&similar_photo_id=15898183&tracking_id=xS4y7pCtoDl-9zdVN1eu3Q&page=1&inline=2707453)?

Comment: @MarkMayo Sorry, but I couldn't find any other appropriate image. I've added image credits if that helps.

Comment: yeah, best to add credit where credit's due, after that it's [a bit hazy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240736/what-should-moderators-or-passing-editors-do-about-suspected-plagiarized-or-co), but at least you've pointed to it now.

Comment: Basago, perhaps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The town you're looking for seems to be [Leh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leh) in the Indian state of Jammu and Kashmir quite [in the north of India](https://www.google.ch/maps/place/Leh/@31.0586374,84.4416045,6z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x38fdeb21445fed85:0xd1bb09975086f710?hl=en). Leh seems to be the common name, but in Tibetian it is written like that: གླེ.

The picture you have mentioned in the question could be either from the [Shey Monastery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shey_Monastery) or similar monasteries such as [Thiksey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thikse_Monastery), or the [Leh Palace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leh_Palace). However, all of them are in the region around Leh.

I found this picture of the Leh Palace on the Internet and it looks quite similar to your picture:

[image]